# Using jquery Autocomplete on textbox control in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-ui

When I run this code I get alert saying Error.

My Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    debugger;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        SearchText();
    });
    function SearchText() {
        $(".auto").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "Default.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData",
                    data: "{'fname':'" + document.getElementById('txtCategory').value + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data.d);
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert("Error");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
</script>

 [WebMethod]
 public static List<string> GetAutoCompleteData(string CategoryName)
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbConnection"].ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select fname from tblreg where fname LIKE '%'+@CategoryText+'%'", con))
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CategoryText", CategoryName);
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    result.Add(dr["fname"].ToString());
                }
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to debug my function GetAutoCompleteData but breakpoint is not fired at all.
What's wrong in this code? Please guide.[image: Error Image]
I have attached screen shot above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the data property's value of you `$.ajax()` call to correctly reflect the C# method parameter i.e. change this line

```
data: "{'fname':'" + document.getElementById('txtCategory').value + "'}",
```

to

```
data: "{'CategoryName':'" + document.getElementById('txtCategory').value + "'}",
```

The data property should match the parameter in the signature of the action method.

Comment: Now talking about the Performance issue, will this code make connection to the sql every time the function will debug? isn`t it wrong approach for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `[WebMethod]` attribute over your method. so your method will look like this

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<string> GetAutoCompleteData(string CategoryName)
{
  ....
```

How to use web method [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

### Edit 1

In your jQuery where you have written `url: "GetAutoCompleteData",` you need to specify the class or page name and then method name.

You cann't directly call Method you need to use the class (.aspx page) and then method.

Comment: Then i get Error 405: Method Not Allowed

Comment: that is what i need to know. But i am unable to find.
i get this alert text saying Error

Comment: This is Not helping :/.

Comment: where you have define the function `public static List<string> GetAutoCompleteData(string CategoryName)`

Comment: I think the error is that the data property does not match the parameter in the signature of the action method, it has the value `fname` instead of `CategoryName`.

Comment: @chridam You are correct. please post this as answer so that i can mark your answer correct

Comment: @Șhȇkhaṝ ,  discussing about the Performance issue, will this code make connection to the sql every time the function will debug? isn`t it wrong approach for doing this?